# log4net configuration - failed to find section

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

This is my error message:

```
log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
       <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>

   <system.serviceModel>
   ...
   </system.serviceModel>

   <connectionStrings>
   ...
   </connectionStrings>

   <log4net>
   ...
   </log4net>

</configuration>
```

What is wrong with my config?

*Update:*

Have also Web.Release.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

    <system.web>
        <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
    ...
    </system.serviceModel>

    <connectionStrings>
    ...
    </connectionStrings>

    <log4net>
    ...   
       <root>
          <level value="DEBUG" xdt:Transform ="Replace"/>
       </root>
    </log4net>

</configuration>
```

Web.Test.cofig - the same as Release one

and Web.Debug.config, that is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">    

</configuration>
```

Comment: I have this error message, but my Logger works fine.

Answer (score 29):

Are you calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` somewhere?

Remove those calls and only add the `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` attribute.

Normally it is easier to configure log4net in a separate file. Create a file `log4net.config` and change your attribute to:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Remove the section in your `web.config`.

Comment: "Are you calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() somewhere?" - no

Comment: This worked.  I guess XmlConfigurator.Configure() isn't used anymore??  This is how I've always done it.  I never had to modify the assembly.cs.  I better read the latest documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, however oddly, I had that line (log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();) in another program and I did not get the log4net error.  However, I feel this is a legitimate solution to the OP issue.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing seems wrong with defining the section under `<configSections>`.

Try adding `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` in your AssemblyInfo.cs in the properties folder of your project. This should do the trick in case your configuration is correct under the  tag.

EDIT :

```
XmlElement log4NetSection = (XmlElement)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net");
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4NetSection);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Siraj. Tried it and nothing happend - the same error message

Comment: Check my Edit and try this piece of code on your "AppStart" or the point execution starts on your application

Comment: Don't forget to add reference to the system.configuration assembly. and add "using System.Configuration"

Comment: It all doesnt helped me, but as I see my Logger works fine event with errot message. But to solve it will be fine )

Comment: @SirajMansour 's EDIT was the solution for me.   I had to do this after upgrading from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.2.